# como puedo simular un evento (onKeyPress) javascript?

Tags: javascript

quiero crear un slider como este de youtube [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde al hacer scroll sobre este, se desplaza en horizontal.

se que al dejar presionado la tecla shift en un campo scrolleable, el scroll cambiar su orientación a horizontal pero me gustaria hacerlo como ese menú de YouTube, que solo con dejar el mouse encima y hacer scroll es como si ya presionase la tecla shift.

Comment: Qué has intentado? Muéstranos algo de código por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el secreto esta en

```
transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(80px);
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar{width:2px;height:2px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button{width:2px;height:2px;}

div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  background: #111;
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:80px;
  max-height:500px;
  margin:0;
  background:green;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-80px);
  transform-origin:right top;
}
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper > div{
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
  background:#cab;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.squares{
  padding:60px 0 0 0;
}

.squares > div{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  margin:10px;
}

.rectangles{
  top:100px;
  padding:100px 0 0 0;
}
.rectangles > div{
  width:140px;
  height:60px;
  margin:50px 10px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#cab;
  transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(80px);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper squares">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
  <div>item 7</div>
  <div>item 8</div>
  <div>item 9</div>
  <div>item 10</div>
  <div>item 11</div>
  <div>item 12</div>
  <div>item 13</div>
  <div>item 14</div>
  <div>item 15</div>
</div>
```

Mas detalles en:
https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/